# Scrolling images , memory warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I need to scroll over 200 images. I ahve found a tutorial that says that I can over 1000 images with the tutorial code. 
The tutorial is:

http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/how-to-load-1000s-of-uiimageview-on.html?m=1

I followed the tutorial, but when I use 100 images aprox..the app crash with memory warning.

My code is here:

http://pastebin.com/BKmsdXxf

I have already with UIIMagenamed, with initWithContentsOfFile

but the problem persist. Pls , help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixeed!

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
CGPoint scrollOffset=scrollView.contentOffset;
int pagAtual = scrollOffset.x/scroll.frame.size.width;
if(pagAtual != 0) { //always release all imageViews and load the current and next
for(int iCnt = 0; iCnt < [scroll.subviews count]; iCnt++) {
    UIView *viewLiberar = [scroll.subviews objectAtIndex:iCnt];
 if ([viewLiberar isKindOfClass:UIImageView.class]) {
    [viewLiberar removeFromSuperview];
     viewLiberar = nil;
   }
 }
}

if(pageOnScrollView < ((int)scrollOffset.x/scroll.frame.size.width))
 { 

 //load the next page
[self loadNextPage:(pagAtual)];
[self loadNextPage:(pagAtual + 1)];
 }
else if(pageOnScrollView > ((int)scrollOffset.x/scroll.frame.size.width))
  {
  if(pagAtual>0)[self loadNextPage:((int)scrollOffset.x/scroll.frame.size.width)-1];
    }

     pageOnScrollView=scrollOffset.x/scroll.frame.size.width;
      }
```